# Azure Search OrderBy case-insensitively

Tags: c#, azure, msdn, case-insensitive, azure-cognitive-search

I am currently using .Net Core 2.2 and I have been using  Microsoft.Azure.Search.Model package to use Azure Search.

Problem: I am unable to achieve OrderBy case-insensitively.

I have researched a bit, but I wasn't able to find clean solution other than creating additional fields on search index which includes all lowercase string fields of the original fields. I do not like this solution because we have over 6 fields that we need to order by. That means, we will have 6 additional fields only for the purpose of sorting in search index, which isn't really optimal solution to me.

```
public override async Task<DocumentSearchResult<ProjectSearchModel>> SearchAsync(ISearchRequest input)
{
    if (input is ProjectSearchRequest request)
    {
        var parameters =
        new SearchParameters(includeTotalResultCount: true)
        {
            Filter = request.Status.Equals("All") ? $"Account eq '{request.Account}'" : $"Account eq '{request.Account}' and Status eq '{request.Status}'",
            OrderBy = new[] { $"Account desc" },
            Top = request.Take,
            Skip = request.Skip
        };

        var searchResult = await base.SearchAsync(parameters, request.Text);
        return searchResult;
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception("Account code is necessary for search in projects. ProjectSearchRequest -> ISearchRequest casting error.");
    }
}
```

The response is sorted by account but uppercase first, and lowercase after. 
For example, z will come after A, which doesn't make sense for our end users.  I would like z to come either right after Z or with Z together.

Comment: what about order the results in memory using linq ?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Unfortunately, I cannot. The search results from the search index will include incorrect data in the first place because it is going to return first 30 items only.

Comment: I think there's something wrong. The standard analyzer already normalize Upper and lower cases: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-analyzers

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Yes, it normalizes Upper and Lower cases for Search, but not when it comes to orderBy. It searches case-insensitively, but it does not order that way.

Comment: You should create a scoring profile that will take care of the proper ordering. More relavant documents will appear first, then you just need to use "$top" since the results will be ordered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the option you suggested (of having extra case normalized fields to use in OrderBy) is the only workaround. You would utilize a token filter to lowercase that field -https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/index-add-custom-analyzers#token-filters

Please vote here so that the search team can prioritize picking it up:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search/suggestions/6328658-case-insensitive-sorting-for-string-fields

Answer (score 1):

Please check out the [Text normalization for case-insensitive filtering, faceting and sorting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers) feature that's in Preview.

You can update your index to use this "normalizer" feature for the fields in which you'd like case-insensitive order-by operations. With this feature, you won't need an extra field anymore.

You don't need a separate field `TitleCaseInsensitive` anymore. You can add `"normalizer": "lowercase"` to the `Account` field, and `$orderBy=Account` will sort in the order you'd like, ignoring casing.

The "lowercase" normalizer is pre-defined. If you'd like other filters to be applied, please look at [predefined and custom normalizers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-normalizers#predefined-normalizers)

```json
"index": {
    "name": "current-local-inventory",  
    "fields": [
        {"name": "Account", "type": "Edm.String", "filterable": true, "sortable": true, "facetable": false, "searchable": true, "normalizer":"lowercase"}
    ]
}
```